# Two \IfEq in \newkeycommand causes failure

Tags: xstring, keycommand

Consider this .tex file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{MWE}
\MWESettings[X=8]{article}
\begin{document}
The answer is \name
\end{document}
```

Where MWE.sty is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MWE}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{keycommand}
\newkeycommand{\MWESettings}[X=1][1]
 {
  \IfEq{#1}{article} { \newcommand{\name}{article \commandkey{X}} } <-- Line A
  \IfEq{#1}{news}    { \newcommand{\name}{news    \commandKey{X}} } <-- Line B
 }
```

If I pdflatex the .tex file I get this error:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \begin{d
            ocument}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you'd like that `\MWEsettings[X=8]{article}` essentially does `\newcommand{\name}{article 8}`?

Comment: No not really. This is just a simplified example.   I actually want it to set up say different page headings depending on the type of manuscript or perhaps other style changes.  Maybe I have over simplified.

Comment: @DonKreher: You can't use your `\MWESettings` command before `\begin{document}` this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, you'd like that

```
\MWESettings[X=8]{article}
```

does

```
\newcommand{\name}{article 8}
```

while

```
\MWESettings[X=5]{news}
```

does

```
\newcommand{\name}{news 5}
```

You're forgetting the “false branch”: it should be

```
\IfEq{<string-a>}{<string-b>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

So this works.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\newkeycommand{\MWESettings}[X=1][1]
 {%
  \IfEq{#1}{article}{\newcommand{\name}{article \commandkey{X}}}{}% <-- Line A
  \IfEq{#1}{news}   {\newcommand{\name}{news    \commandkey{X}}}{}% <-- Line B
 }

\MWESettings[X=8]{article}

\begin{document}
The answer is \name
\end{document}
```

Note also that you're introducing many unwanted spaces in your code.

It's not clear why not directly using `#1` instead of the `\IfEq` text, but I guess this is a simplified example.

Not that I recommend `keycommand`. A different implementation with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MWESettings}{O{X=1}m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { kreher/mwe } { #1 }
  \cs_new:Npx \name
   {
    \str_case:nn { #2 }
     {
      {article}{article}
      {news}{news}
     }~\l_kreher_mwe_x_tl
   }
 }
\keys_define:nn { kreher/mwe }
 {
  X .tl_set:N = \l_kreher_mwe_x_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\MWESettings[X=8]{article}

\begin{document}
The answer is \name
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that was it.  I misread the IfEq command.  What unwanted space am I introducing?  Yes its a very simplified example. The xparse example looks way more complicated.

Comment: @DonKreher: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer . Yes you can.

Comment: @Werner I do see how your comment on (%) applies here.

Comment: @DonKreher TeX is made for typesetting, so spaces usually count.